# Django - POST is_valid() false, no erro and no writing into the db

Tags: python, django, database, post

i have a simple html form, where i can add some data and submit it to be added to the db.

this is the form:

```
 <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->

    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="section__content section__content--w1830">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <h1>Artikel</h1>
                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Artikel hinzufügen</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label for="type" class="control-label mb-1">Typ</label>
                                        <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control"
                                                value=" {{ forms.artikel_typ }} ">
                                            <option value="0">Bitte auswählen</option>
                                            <option value="1">Raum</option>
                                            <option value="2">Artikel</option>
                                            <option value="3">Gerät</option>
                                            <option value="4">Marketing</option>
                                            <option value="5">Labor</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8">
                                        <label for="bezeichnung" class="control-label mb-1"> Bezeichnung</label>
                                        <input id="bezeichnung" name="bezeichnung" type="text" class="form-control"
                                               data-val="true"
                                               data-val-required="Bitte tragen Sie eine Bezeichnung ein!"
                                               aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"
                                               placeholder="Bitte tragen Sie eine Bezeichnung ein." value ="{{ forms.bezeichnung }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body card-block">
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label for="menge" class="control-label mb-1">Menge</label>
                                        <input id="menge"  type="number"
                                               class="form-control" data-val="ture"
                                               data-val-required="Bitte tragen Sie die Menge ein!"
                                               aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"
                                               placeholder="Bitte geben Sie die Menge an." value=" {{ forms.menge }} ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label for="einheit" class="control-label mb-1">Einheit</label>
                                        <select name="einheit" value="{{ forms.einheit }}" id="einheit"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                data-val-required="Bitte tragen Sie die Einheit ein!"
                                                aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                                            <option value="0">Bitte auswählen</option>
                                            <option value="Euro">Euro</option>
                                            <option value="Prozent">Prozent</option>
                                            <option value="Minuten">Minuten</option>
                                            <option value="Stück">Stück</option>
                                            <option value="pauschal">pauschal</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label for="preis">Preis</label>
                                        <input id="preis" value="{{ forms.preis }}" step="0.01" type="number"
                                               class="form-control"
                                               data-val="ture"
                                               data-val-required="Bitte tragen Sie den Preis ein!"
                                               aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"
                                               placeholder="Bitte tragen Sie den Preis ein!">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="card-footer">
                                
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="post" action="articles">
                                    <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Artikel hinzufügen
                                </button>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    </form>

                </div>

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <div class="table-responsive table--no-card m-b-30">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>id</th>
                                        <th>artikel_typ</th>
                                        <th>bezeichnung</th>
                                        <th>menge</th>
                                        <th>preis</th>
                                        <th>einheit</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for d in data %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ == 1 %}
                                                <td> Raum</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 2 %}
                                                <td> Artikel</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 3 %}
                                                <td> Gerät</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 4 %}
                                                <td> Marketing</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 5 %}
                                                <td> Labor</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <td>{{ d.bezeichnung }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ d.menge }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ d.preis }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ d.einheit }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER-->
```

this is the views.py part of the code that is use:

```
def articles(request):

data = Artikel.objects.all()
aform = ArtikelForm( data=request.POST or None)

if request.method == "POST":

    if aform.is_valid():
        artikel_type = aform.cleaned_data['artikel_typ']
        bezeichnung = aform.cleaned_data['bezeichnung']
        menge =  aform.cleaned_data['menge']
        preis =  aform.cleaned_data['preis']
        einheit =  aform.cleaned_data['einheit']
        artikel = Artikel(artikel_typ=artikel_type, bezeichnung=bezeichnung, menge=menge, preis=preis, einheit=einheit)
        artikel.save()

    return redirect("articles")


return render(request, "articles.html", {"data": data, "forms": aform})
```

this is the forms.py which i defined:

```
from django import forms
```

class ArtikelForm(forms.Form):

```
artikel_typ = forms.IntegerField()
bezeichnung = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
menge = forms.FloatField()
preis = forms.FloatField()
einheit = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and this is the model defined in models.py:

```
class Artikel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    artikel_typ = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    bezeichnung = models.TextField()
    menge = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    preis = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    einheit = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

so i tried the model, form and in the python console. I added the data to a dict, created an instance of the ArtikelForm and called is_valid() and it returned true and the cleaned_data looked good.

However, when the form is submitted, is_valid() returns falls, and the field values return None for the integer and float fields, the char fields are retrieved and show the infos i entered/ selected, HTTP response is 200 and gets redirected. Does anyone have a solution to how i could solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems you have going on here and I will try to explain them in detail. Whenever you make a form in Django you have to make a class for it which defines all the fields and how to the form is to be "built" which you have done correctly in `forms.py`. Even though you did that properly you might want to look into inheriting from `forms.ModelForm` since it will make that form creation easier. Basically a `ModelForm` will automatically make a form for you given a `Model`. Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)
for more info on that.

Where the real magic happens is the `views.py` where you handle the request and return the rendered html with the appropriate form. What you have done is query your Model for some objects `data = Artikel.objects.all()` then create the form `aform = ArtikelForm( data=request.POST or None)` and then you check if the method is a `POST` request in order to validate the form and do some other things. However, at the bottom when you do your return you are not passing the form to the html. You need to ensure you pass a dictionary with everything for example `return render(request, 'articles.html', {'data': data, 'forms': aform})`. This should fix the issue of not being able to access your form from the template. But this means you will access a specific field in the form like so: `{{ forms.artikel_typ }}`.

Also I want to point out, in your `views.py` to access the data inside a form to save to a model you normally want to get the "cleaned data". This is something Django does to make sure all the fields turn into some sort of python standard to easily use it and save it to a model. The way you access this is by doing `aform.cleaned_data['artikel_typ']`. Also maybe look into using [crispy forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so you don't have to manually make your form.

**EDIT**

In your html template all you need to do is access `{{ forms.field_name }}` and it will put in the html for that field widget. There is no need to create the form manually and that is why you use Django forms. See below:

```
 <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->

    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="section__content section__content--w1830">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <h1>Artikel</h1>
                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Artikel hinzufügen</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ forms.artikel_typ }}
                            {{ forms.bezeichnung }}
                            {{ forms.menge }}
                            {{ forms.preis }}
                            {{ forms.einheit }}
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <div class="table-responsive table--no-card m-b-30">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>id</th>
                                        <th>artikel_typ</th>
                                        <th>bezeichnung</th>
                                        <th>menge</th>
                                        <th>preis</th>
                                        <th>einheit</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for d in data %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ == 1 %}
                                                <td> Raum</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 2 %}
                                                <td> Artikel</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 3 %}
                                                <td> Gerät</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 4 %}
                                                <td> Marketing</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if  d.artikel_typ  == 5 %}
                                                <td> Labor</td>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <td>{{ d.bezeichnung }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ d.menge }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ d.preis }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ d.einheit }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER-->
```

This will access each field individually if you want to rearrange where they go and do some styling but you can also simply use `{{ forms }}` and that will render all the fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! I got a step further with your instructions. But my form is rendered wrong when i add the forms tags. the {{ forms.artikel_typ }} works fine and doesn't change anything. Starting with {{ forms.bezeichnung }} the thing goes wild and html tags show up in the form. :|

Comment: Can you update your post with your new code please?

Comment: Ok so basically ```{{ forms.bezeichung }}``` is returning the actual form widget that corresponds to that field name in the form. There is no need to create the field in your template. Let me edit my answer to kind of show you what I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D you say there is no need to do it manually, but if i'ld want to, could i? 

Comment: you say there is no need to do it manually, but if i'ld want to, how could i do it? any hints where i could look it up? 

Comment: By manually I meant getting one field at a time instead of all of them in order to group them or rearrange them. This you simply do by calling the specific field by ```{{ forms.field_name }}```  What is it that you wish to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to style the buttons and I didn't know how. After looking at the links you've suggested i found out how to do that in forms.py! Thanks a lot! Yet again another reason why i love the Django and Python community: bcs of cool ppl like u!